# How to Extract a Substring From a String from any character position

Tags: sql, string, salesforce, substring, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am facing an issue while writing a query to extract a substring from a string available in my data extension.
I have a field with data in this format {"Body":"Hi TestSFMC"}. I want to extract only  the Substring- TestSFMC , from the given field.
Here is my query -
Select
SUBSTRING(a.MessageData, CHARINDEX(':',a.MessageData)+2, LEN(a.MessageData)-2) AS MessageData
From FabriCare_WA_Inbound_Message_DetailsDE a
The issue with the query is I'm getting the required output with a slight issue, that its giving the end double quote and end curly brace, after the substring. Like my current output is - Hi TestSFMC"}

And i want only Hi TestSFMC, as output. Can anyone help me with my query ?

Many thanks in advance.

Here is my query -
Select
SUBSTRING(a.MessageData, CHARINDEX(':',a.MessageData)+2, LEN(a.MessageData)-2) AS MessageData
From FabriCare_WA_Inbound_Message_DetailsDE a
The issue with the query is I'm getting the required output with a slight issue, that its giving the end double quote and end curly brace, after the substring. Like my current output is - Hi TestSFMC"}

And i want only Hi TestSFMC, as output. Can anyone help me with my query ?

Answer (score 0):

try like this one:

Declare @MessageData nvarchar(max)='{"Body":"Hi TestSFMC"}'
select replace(SUBSTRING(@MessageData, CHARINDEX(':',@MessageData)+2, LEN(@MessageData)-2),'"}','')

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is also not giving me expected output. Like quote in right side remains same. Like Hi TestSFMC" . But anyways thanks. I have used this-  SELECT
  REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(a.MessageData, '$.Body'), '"', '') AS MessageData
FROM FabriCare_WA_Inbound_Message_DetailsDE a
And its wokring.